# Deleting certain rows/columns in a grid Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

If I have several rows and columns with several entry/label widgets in the SAME frame, is it possible to choose just a single one of them and delete it whilst leaving the others alone.

e.g.

```
class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.win1 = Frame(self.root)
        entry1 = Entry(win1, row=1, column=1)
        entry2 = Entry(win1, row=1, column=2)
        label1 = Label(win1, row=1, column=3)

    def main1(self):
        label2 = Label(win1, row=1, column=4)
        labeln = Label(win1, row=1, column=n)
```

I would then like to remove from column 3 onwards, where n could be a random number. Is it possible to get grid_forget and insert the number of columns? Is it also possible for the rows as well?

UPDATE: OR is it possible to simply return back to the window created under **init** and delete those created under main1 (but have been created in the same frame)?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are asking is kind of dynamic layout for tk. I had tried it before and IMO it's not possible.
hence i took an indirect approach. Please check my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I really don't want to make it too complicated. Is there maybe a way in which to clear my main window and then reinstate the __init__ widgets etc?

Comment: @Ani: "it's not possible" is completely false. There is nothing from preventing you to create a highly dynamic UI. Arguably, tkinter is much more capable of this than many other toolkits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the grid_remove and grid_forget methods; these will alow you to remove existing widgets from view. You can also destroy widgets, causing them to vanish.

It's been a while since I've done this (and don't currently have a computer on which to create an example), but I think the one sticky point may be that you will have to go in and explicitly set the grid row and/or column heights, widths or weights back to zero to reclaim the space. It's quite doable though.

Your other choice is to create all of your widgets via a method or function. You can then pretty easily destroy and recreate all the widgets. This is probably less pleasant for the user since the whole UI will "blink".

Comment: Thanks =) I have tried this and have succeeded in removing 3 our of 4 boxes that I have (not directly linked to my brief example in the question). The final box has been removed but there is still something there since the background colour remains in this space. Any ideas?

Comment: In fact I have two occasions where I need this to happen (depending on an option in an if statement) and it deletes all but the one box but leaves the root window background colour and the other option almost manages to delete all of it but you can still see it peeking out at the end of the window.. =S

Comment: @user2063: if the background color is showing, that means there is nothing there. As I said in the answer, you might have to set the weight of a column or row to zero so that the other columns or rows expand to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a csh script to create a dynamic python code for GUI.

**What it does?**

enter

> ./dynamic_python -label name,age -frame myframe

and it will create 2 label named name,age , 2 entry box for each label and some other widgets.
I know it's not exactly what you need, but consider it at a possible approach to your solution.
Ping me if you need more help.
Will appreciate other user's feedback :)

CODE for dynamic_python:

```
#! /bin/csh -f

#echo $argv[1]
#shift
#echo $argv[1]
while ("$#" != 0)
    if("$argv[1]" == "-label") then 
        set label = "$argv[2]"
        shift
        shift
    endif
    if("$argv[1]" == "-frame") then 
        set frame = "$argv[2]"
        shift
        shift
    endif
end
set label = `echo $label | sed 's/,/ /g'`
set lcount = `expr "$#label" + 1`
set lc = 1
#
echo "#! /usr/bin/python" > dy.py
echo "from Tkinter import *" >> dy.py
#
echo "def fun_ok():" >> dy.py
echo "  print 'OK_Accepted'" >> dy.py
set label = `echo $label | sed 's/,/ /g'`
set lcount = `expr "$#label" + 1`
set lc = 1
echo "  list_out = []" >> dy.py
while ($lc != $lcount)
    echo "  print $label[$lc].get()" >> dy.py
    echo "  list_out.append('-$label[$lc]')" >> dy.py
    echo "  list_out.append($label[$lc].get())" >> dy.py
    set lc = `expr "$lc" + 1`
end
echo "  print list_out" >> dy.py
#
echo "$frame = Tk()" >> dy.py
#
set label = `echo $label | sed 's/,/ /g'`
set lcount = `expr "$#label" + 1`
set lc = 1
while ($lc != $lcount)
    echo $lc $label[$lc]
    echo "$label[$lc] = StringVar()" >> dy.py
    echo "Label($frame,text="_$label[$lc]_").grid(row = $lc,column = 1)" | sed 's/_/"/g' >> dy.py
    echo "Entry($frame,textvariable=$label[$lc]).grid(row=$lc,column=2)" >> dy.py
    set lc = `expr "$lc" + 1`
end
echo "Button($frame,text='OK',command=fun_ok).grid(row = $lc,column = 1)" >> dy.py
echo "Button($frame,text='EXIT',command=$frame.quit).grid(row = $lc,column = 2)" >> dy.py
#Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
#
echo "$frame.mainloop()" >> dy.py
#
chmod 755 *
dy.py
```

Comment: -1 sorry, but that is just way too complex and hard to maintain.

Comment: @BryanOakley I agree its hard to maintain. I hope to learn someway to do it.