# How to remove widgets from grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a grid in a tkinter frame which displays query results. It has a date field that is changed manually and then date is used as a parameter on the query for those results. every time the date is changed, obviously the results change, giving a different amount of rows. The problem is that if you get less rows the second time you do it, you will still have results from the first query underneath those and will be very confusing.

My question is, how can i remove all rows from the frame that have a row number greater than 6 (regardless of what's in it)?

By the way, I'm running Python 3.3.3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post some code to give me an idea of how you've set your code up so the response makes sense.

Comment: also see Brian Oakley's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357988/deleting-certain-rows-columns-in-a-grid-tkinter) that pretty much does what your asking doesn't it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Calling the method `grid_forget` on the widget will remove it from the window - 
this example uses the call `grid_slaves` on the parent to findout all 
widgets mapped to the grid, and then the `grid_info` call to learn about
each widget's position:

```
>>> import tkinter
# create: 
>>> a = tkinter.Tk()
>>> for i in range(10):
...    label = tkinter.Label(a, text=str(i))
...    label.grid(column=0, row=i)
# remove from screen:
>>> for label in a.grid_slaves():
...    if int(label.grid_info()["row"]) > 6:
...       label.grid_forget()
```

Comment: awesom! that's pretty much what i'm looking for! on question though, how would i be able to do this if i don't know the widgets name?

Comment: The snipped above shows exactly that: it does not use any python-side references to the widgets at all, rather it retrieves the widgets and its positions through the method calls. (Of course you need a reference to the parent widget)

Comment: Chiming in from 2020, this is still an exceptionally viable option. Well done @jsbueno.

Comment: grid_forget() does not remove a widget, it only hides it. That can be a memory leak if widgets are constantly forgotten/hidden and then new widgets created.

Comment: indeed - the widget will leak - however, I just made some experiments here using weakref to check wether a widget is actually "gone", and it seems they will leak anyway, even after removing from all layout managers, calling "destroy", and, of course, deleting all Python-side references.  The widget still can be retrieved via the weakref. Just don't do an app that creates a list of hundreds of widgets and tries to kill then all and create new ones upon refresh. You'd be out of some GB on your desktop after a week or so.

Comment: sorry if this sounds passive-agressive I just could not let got of the joke. The conclusion is tkinter apps will leak objects anyway,  and if you are working on an appliance intended to have an app "always" on, remember to set up a supervisor to restart it when appropriate in all cases. However, of course, a proper program _should_ also call .destroy() and remove Python side references to any widget it is not reusing.