# tkinter grid_forget method

Tags: python, tkinter

The program I am creating updates the page with new data once the submit button is clicked, in the function for the submit button, it creates the labels (8 of them).

```
row = 7
step = 0

for k,v in ordnance_database.items():
    name = v
    label = Label(window, text=(name + ": " + str(ship_ordnance[step])),
                  background=background_colour, foreground="white", font="none 10")
    label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=W, columnspan=2)

    all_labels.append(label)
    row += 1
    step += 1
```

When the submit button is clicked again, it creates new labels but the previous ones are still there. After a bit of googling and searching in the reference I found this:
[How to remove widgets from grid in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189610/how-to-remove-widgets-from-grid-in-tkinter) and added this in the submit button's function:

```
for labels in window.grid_slaves():
    if 7 < int(labels.grid_info()["row"]) < 15 and int(labels.grid_info()["column"]) == 0:
        labels.grid_forget()
    else:
        pass
```

I would like to clear the contents of the grids with row values 7 to 14, and in column 0.

I have tried adding window.update() but this made no difference.

I have confirmed that to `labels.grid_forget()` is being triggered using `print()` but it's not actually clearing them from the screen.

I have also tried using `.configure` - something like this

```
labels.configure(text="Loading")
```

but no joy.

Here are screenshots from the program showing the issue. On the second button click you can see "Homing: 8" has the previous data hidden behind it.

[image: First button click]

[image: Second button click]

Comment: Do you have to hide the label and create new one? or you just need to update the text of the label?

Comment: You say that you want to clear rows 7 to 14, but your code actually clears rows 8 to 14... any chance that the "Homing" label is in row 7, and happens to be the only one being left behind?  Note that `.grid_forget()` isn't what you want anyway, as it leaves all of the old widgets in memory for possible reuse - you want `.destroy()`.

Comment: Have you considered printing out the names of the widgets as you create them, and then printing out the names of the widgets that you're trying to remove, to see if the two lists of widgets are the same?

Comment: If there are always 8 Labels then you should be able to create them once and use their `configure()` method to update their appearance as many times as necessary. If you tried that and it didn't work, then you did something wrong — however what's currently in your question is insufficient for anyone to determine how to fix it. Please [edit] your question a provide a [mre].

Comment: @jasonharper - I'm an idiot! Well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

The `grid_forget()` method will just hide the label, it won't remove the label.

If you want to remove the label, use `destroy()`.
Now, if the objective here is just to update the label text, you can use
`StringVar()`

```
row = 7
step = 0
for k,v in ordnance_database.items():
    name = v
    lbl_text_var = StringVar()
    lbl_text_var.set(name + ": " + str(ship_ordnance[step]))
    label = Label(window, textvariable=lbl_text_var, background=background_colour, foreground="white", font="none 10")
    # Setting text variable as it's own attribute to retrieve it later.
    # a separate list can also be created
    label.lbl_text_var = lbl_text_var
    all_labels.append(label)
    row += 1
    step += 1
```

now when you want to set the values

```
step = 0
for k,v in ordnance_database.items():
    name = v
    lbl_text_var = all_labels[step].lbl_text_var
    lbl_text_var.set(name + ": " + str(ship_ordnance[step]))
    step += 1
```